# Round robin pattern with 2 thread pools , java 8 and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency, java-8

**Problem statement**

We have 2 thread pools. One is main thread pool A (consisting of threads A1,A2,...An) and other is secondary thread pool B.Each thread from thread pool A have a certain number of tasks that it can submit to thread pool B.I want to have an constraint that each thread from pool A (say A1) can have N tasks submitted and in progress to thread pool B at any given point of time.If any of the tasks submitted to pool B gets completed, A1 can submit next task until all tasks belonging to A1 gets completed.

Basic idea behind this is to implement a round robin processing pattern for threads in thread pool A.

I am using spring boot 4 and java 8

Looking for best approach to implement this scenario.

Comment: ... and you have tried what?

Comment: I am quite new to concurrent prog. so i first looked into some popular classes used to solve these kind of problems like Countdownlatch and CyclicBarrier with no luck.Then i thought of writing a custom class say TokenCounter which can be used by each thread in  
 pool A which has some object like pool of tokens which can be accessed with method getToken().If there is no token available in pool then ask the calling thread to wait and if there is a token return the token.After completion of task thread in pool B return token to TokenCounter. Got stuck on token pool type and not sure if m r8

Comment: A “thread from thread pool A” can’t submit tasks to another thread pool (unless you’re mixing up terms). Only *tasks* can submit new tasks, but when you submit a task to thread pool A, you have no control over which of A’s threads will execute the task, therefore there is no sense in trying to limit submissions of tasks to B based on the *thread* of A.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad,I used thread instead of task. As i mentioned each of pool A's task(assume A1) contains some fixed number of tasks(assume 1000) to be submitted to pool B. I don't need to know which of the A's task is currently executing. I just want that A1 should at most submit 20 of its tasks to pool B and wait.If any one of 20 tasks gets completed push 21st task to pool B.Continue this until all 1000 tasks have been submitted and executed by pool B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys !

I was able to solve the problem by taking TokenCounter and Token helper classes. TokenCounter acts as a store for tokens which asks the calling thread to wait if no token is available in store else just returns the token. On the other hand a Token always know with which store it is associated. So when we submit a task from pool A to pool B we pass a token with the task. Pool B thread after executing the assigned task releases the token which gets submitted back to the TokenCounter linked with it and is available now to all waiting threads if any.In this way we can limit the number of tokens available for each task in pool A which it uses to submit tasks to pool B.

Reference :

https://github.com/parvbansal/solutionsRepo
(I have used a scheduler to initiate and submit tasks in pool A after a certain amount of time)